# What is a "mock euphemism?"

Tags: meaning, grammar, etymology, phrases, nouns

I have to make flashcards for my AP Lang class, but I can't find what a "mock euphemism" is anywhere. Can anyone help?

Comment: You know *euphemism* - a "nice" way of saying something unpleasant, e.g. "passed away" instead of "died".  A  **mock  euphemism** would be a sarcastic turn of phrase that looks like a euphemism at first glance, but is in fact nastier than the original phrase it replaces: e.g. "assumed room temperature" instead of "died".

Comment: "Where's Dunbar?" Yossarian wanted to know."**They disappeared him.**" "What do you mean *they disappeared him*? *Catch-22* by Joseph Heller (Dunbar was deliberately killed)

Comment: @MT_Head: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Room temperature IQ (worse in countries using Celsius)

Comment: Or, as the Austrian uhlans did to Marechal Berthier June 1, 1815: "They **defenestrated** him." Which is to say, deposited him head-down outside the glass of the 3rd floor window, with force.

Answer (score 5):

A [*euphemism*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/euphemism) is a "nice" way of saying something unpleasant, e.g. "passed away" instead of "died".

A ***mock*** euphemism would be a sarcastic turn of phrase that looks like a euphemism at first glance, but is in fact nastier than the original phrase it replaces: e.g. "assumed room temperature" instead of "died".

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, rather than an answer. But since I can't format the comment correctly, here's a quote from [Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0007552/quotes).

> Slartibartfast: You must come with me.
>
> Arthur Dent: Who are you?
>
> Slartibartfast: What? No. My name's not important. You must come with me, or you'll be late.
>
> Arthur Dent: Late for what?
>
> Slartibartfast: Well, um, what's your name Earthman?
>
> Arthur Dent: Dent. Arthur Dent.
>
> Slartibartfast: Well, late as in *the late* Dentarthurdent.

It's a sort of threat. You see?